# Where to find package manager in Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: package-management

I'm a newbie to linux and I have a Xubuntu 13.10 relase installed on my PC. I need to install some packages for web development but I can not find the package manager utility in the applications menu. Could somebody tell me where I can find it?

Answer (score 8):

One of the package managers available is the Ubuntu software center, which is available on the main menu.

[image]

Or you can use synaptic package manager.  To install it if not installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```